# Encrypting a textfile using the given schemes in C++

Tags: c++, encryption, transpose

Let me start off by saying yes this is an assignment and I am not looking for a full working code. I may just need a snippet or two and a bit of idea. So in this program

1. the user is asked for the original file which will contain some
   text.
2. the user is asked for an output file where the encrypted text will
   be put
3. User is asked for an encryption key n(in this case a number)
4. Read n*n characters from the file into the n rows and n columns of a
   2 dimensional array.
5. Transpose the array (exchange the rows and columns.
6. write the characters from the array to the output file
7. repeat steps 4-6.

Basically I can do all of this but the place where this gets confusing to me is step 7...the repeat part, this sounds weird but its because of the following reasons.

Program should have functions for performing the following tasks.

1. Reading the characters from the file into the array.  This function
   should be passed the input file stream, the array and the key.

   (So,I am guessing in this function will be putting the characters from the input file into the 2 dimensional array. The confusion I am having is should this function be a void or should it return the 2 dimensional array. I am guessing I will have to return the array since I will need to transpose it but then again the specification says that in this function the array should be passed. Also when you get a character from a file how do you assign it to a 2 dimensional array.
2. Transposing the array.  This function should be passed the array and
   the key.

   (Ok I can do the transposition. It's just the exchange of rows and columns. Also do I return the array again to be written in the output file?)
   This is how the text would look after transposing.

[image]

3. Writing the characters from the array to the file.  This function should be passed the output file stream, the array and the key. 
   If the first 16 characters of the input file are the following

"THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER T"

and your key is 4, then the first 16 characters of your output file would be 
"TQKOHU WEIBN CR FJSEOU RXMO  PVT" 
but now the question remains how do i repeat this process for the remaining text.

Again I just need the idea. I am not asking anyone to code it for me. Thank you.

Comment: At a guess I'd say you are expected to pass the array to the function *by reference*. (If you're not sure what that means, look it up-- it's a crucial concept.) In practice that means you pass a pointer to the first element in the array. That takes care of most of your points.

Comment: Placing the array in a structure, then passing the structure may make the function signatures easier.

Answer (score 0):

And I would also suggest that you want to transpose the whole file, not just the first nxn elements.

You will want to read nxn elements from the file,
transpose them,
then read the next nxn elements, transpose them,
then read the next nxn elements, transpose them,
(etc)